# Convert UID null-termintated string binary to hex

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here is the question which is Re Phrased.

Here is the raw binary data, hex encoded, which i need as a output:
040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000310000007643616C2D5569640100000033353335324538372D343338462D343444362D413432462D37393942423334313033333800

I can extract some part of the raw data i.e.(040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000310000007643616C2D55696401000000) from the object which i am getting  from the micro soft outlook.

The Rest of the part that is 
**33353335324538372D343338462D343444362D413432462D373939424233343130333338** is the conversion of the UID : 373D06E9-587E-4930-B846-12500FF1AC2F.

So My question here is how to convert the above UID i.e 373D06E9-587E-4930-B846-12500FF1AC2F to this format  33353335324538372D343338462D343444362D413432462D373939424233343130333338 using objective C or cocoa.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Binary to hexadecimal or hexadecimal to binary?

Comment: Need to convert UID to Binary and then need to convert binary to hexadecimal

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please clarify what you have exactly and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Maddy, I have a UID "373D06E9-587E-4930-B846-12500FF1AC2F" which needs to be converted to Binary format first and then it needs to be converted to hexa decimal format.

Comment: It's already hexadecimal. What do you mean by "binary format"? What does sample output look like?

Comment: I mean be specific. What data types do you have and want? Show some relevant code.

Comment: I need to convert  373D06E9-587E-4930-B846-12500FF1AC2F to "33353335324538372D343338462D343444362D413432462D373939424233343130333338"

Comment: @Guss Given the number of close votes I'd suggest you edit the question with the extra information from your comments to improve it.

Comment: @Guss - The second string you give in your comment above appears to be a string formed by taking each character of a UUID string and replacing it by the two character hex representation of its unicode value - only its the result of doing that to a different UUID (`"35352E87-448F-44D6-A42F-799BB3410338"`). Are you looking at a memory dump? What are you trying to do? See Richard Banks' comment, you need to help folk to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look here:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreateFromString

CFUUIDCreateFromString() appears to be the API you are looking for.  Assuming that CFUUID is the "binary format" you are searching for.

If you then want "raw bytes", look at CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes()

Comment: My answer is no longer appropriate since you have changed the question